# Svelte: Component context

Tags: svelte

I created a custom dropdown component.
I have multiples instances of it on the same page like this:

```
label : <Select>
label : <Select>
label : <Select>
```

Whenever I click on the  component, the first one opens only. How can I fix this?
Thank you.

// Select.svelte

```
<div class="dropdown">
<slot></slot>
</div>
```

SelectItem.svelte

```
<Select>
 content
</Select>
```

items.svelte

```
{#each items as item}
<item />
{/each}
```

item.svelte

```
<SelectItem/>
```

Comment: Can you post any relevant code? Can't say without seeing how it works

Comment: Sure, thank you! I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have something like this

```html
<script>
//App.svelte
    import Select from "./Select.svelte"
    let options = [
        {label:"State 1", id:1},
        {label:"State 2", id:2}
    ]
    let country = [
        {label:"Country 1", id:1},
        {label:"Country 2", id:2}
    ]
</script>


<Select options={options}/>

<Select options={country} />
```

```html
<script>
//Select.svelte
    export let options = []
</script>


<select>
        {#each options as option} 
            <option>{option.label}</option>
        {/each}
</select>
```

Check [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/244fff3db6ec4f7080795f71c5c49906?version=3.35.0)